# Alfresco deployment on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat6, alfresco

I'm building Alfresco from source and want to deploy it on Tomcat. Can please anybody explain this to me ? There is not enough information about it [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SVN_Development_Environment) .

```
APP_TOMCAT_HOME (can be used to host the Slingshot webapp)

VIRTUAL_TOMCAT_HOME (NOTE: this must be a totally separate installation of Tomcat; it is required for virtualization)
```

I suppose that APP_TOMCAT_HOME can be the same location as TOMCAT_HOME, but what about the virtualization ? What is it about ? Why ?

I found [this thread](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=20896) and it is like :

> Forget about virtualization server

- In that case, the build script deploys stuff in to  ${env.var.that.is.not.set}

I end up with

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener
```

From what I read in here [Virtualization_Server_FAQ](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Virtualization_Server_FAQ) , I don't need it at all, but the build script kinda count on the VIRTUAL_TOMCAT_HOME variable and it deploys some tomcat 5.x stuff like common and server directories

Finally I tried to find what is going on in [this wiki entry](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Install_Tomcat6) but it is also "out of context" ...

This is How far I got :

```
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 28, 2011 4:24:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 466 ms
Feb 28, 2011 4:24:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 28, 2011 4:24:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Feb 28, 2011 4:24:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor alfresco.xml
Feb 28, 2011 4:24:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
16:24:55,574  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/repository.properties]
16:24:55,576  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/domain/transaction.properties]
16:24:55,619  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/alfresco-shared.properties]
16:24:55,727  INFO  [alfresco.config.FixedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/version.properties]
16:24:55,760  INFO  [alfresco.config.FixedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/domain/cache-strategies.properties]
16:25:07,058  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
16:25:07,061  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
16:25:14,227  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Schema managed by database dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect.
16:25:14,481  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] No changes were made to the schema.
1    6:25:14,531  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
16:25:14,543  INFO  [alfresco.config.FixedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/version.properties]
16:25:14,543  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/alfresco-shared.properties]
16:25:14,544  INFO  [alfresco.config.FixedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/domain/cache-strategies.properties]
16:25:14,554  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:50504]" Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:50506]" Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:50502]" Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:50505]" Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:50508]" Exception in thread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:50501]" Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
```

environment:

```
Alfresco Revision 25908
tomcat 6.0.29
java version "1.6.0_16"
linux x86_64
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The virtualization server is a customized Tomcat instance that is used to run the Java application that implements the presentation layer of structured content managed through a WCM project in Alfresco. The ant script provides a way to apply the customizations to a standard Tomcat distributions to enable it to work as a [virtualization server](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Virtualization_Server_FAQ). You can safely ignore it, most likely.

`APP_TOMCAT_HOME` should point to a Tomcat distribution folder that will host Alfresco Share, while `TOMCAT_HOME` will host Alfresco Repository. They can be the same server.

I was able to reproduce the very same issue, which appears to occur when the Tomcat process runs out of memory during Alfresco deployment. Try again with increased memory limits, like:

```
tomcat-6.0.29$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m"
tomcat-6.0.29$ bin/startup.sh
```

Have a look also to the suggested [JVM settings](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JVM_Tuning).

Comment: Thanks skuro, I increased the memory, without it I wouldn't get to the problem with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ... I gave it up... I rather stick to jackrabbit and liferay... I've never seen such a mess in deployment and lack of current documentation for such a essential thing ... regarding software of this caliber.

Comment: I set up loggers for particular classes to TRACE mode but I didn't manage to figure out the problem, everything looked like in the alfresco package with install script...

Comment: It's really strange it didn't work for you, I tried with the HEAD from yesterday and it worked pretty fine, with the Exception disappearing after increasing available memory to the app server. On a side note, I agree Alfresco could make developers life easier to bootstrap their code.